# chrome > console.info > prints in black ( same as console.log )

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone experience this situation where you do

`console.info ('hi');
hi // And this hi is printed in black color as opposed to blue`

Screenshot from the console:
https://postimg.org/image/g8isebbrn/

console.info was used to print in blue for years! Now to my surprise, not anymore.

I could not find any setting on chrome that makes the output go color-blind like that!

Comment: Chrome developers decided you don't need it https://crbug.com/712103

Comment: makes one speechless. do you know of any extension to bring the sense back?

Answer (score 3):

looks like this is indented by design, go figure, but.. here is a way out as an alternative!

`console.log("%cThis will be formatted with large, blue text", "color: blue; font-size: x-large");`

do NOT forget the `%c` in there!

To wrap it in a function, you can use this kick-starter code for you:

```
function sysConsole(messageType,message){ 
    if ( messageType === 'info') {
      s = '%c' + '##' + messageType + ': ' + message; 
      // the ## will enable you to do filtering at the console 
      // by typing ##info 
      console.log (s, 'color: blue;'); 
    }

    // you can have other messageTypes later (to be wired for different colors )

    return false;
  }
```

for future inspiration, go to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write

Comment: Was `console.info` removed? It's mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#consoleinfoobject_object